# Is it possible to unstage (or reset) a file in SourceTree and, if so, how is it done?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, sourcetree

Consider the case where you have a working copy with 2 changed files, which you want to commit individually (IE: make 2 commits).  Using git directly you can:

```
git add change1.txt
```

to "stage" `change1.txt` for the next commit.  If you then decide you want to commit `change2.txt` first, you can:

```
git reset change1.txt
git add change2.txt
```

to swap the files between staging/working copy *without undoing the changes in the files*.

I am trying to help a colleague do this using a GUI - in this case, [SourceTree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) by Atlassian - but I can't figure it out.

There is an "Add" command, which successfully adds a file to the staging area.  However, there is no "reset" command (at least none I can find).  There is a "Remove" command, but using it warns:

> The following files contain changes or information which is not in source control, and will be irretrievably lost if you remove them:

Which means it cant be simply moving the file from staging back to working copy (like `git reset` would do).

Is there any way to perform a simple "un-stage" as described for `change1.txt` above using SourceTree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the file(s) and click "Unstage Selected":

[image]

Comment: I wasn't seeing those buttons, but see that hamburger button directly above your red box?  That contains an option "Split View Staging" which made the buttons appear.  Thanks - but what a stupid interface!

Comment: @AlexMcMillan -- weird!  Yeah, that is kind of an odd option to have.  Glad this helped!